# Helm Release Issue

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, kubernetes-pod, amazon-eks

I am getting the above error every time we deploy from Jenkins.Error: UPGRADE FAILED: release xxxx-xxxxx-config failed, and has been rolled back due to atomic being set: timed out waiting for the condition

LOGS:

```
[2021-02-02T07:44:38.872Z] + helm upgrade --atomic --timeout 600s --install --namespace xxxx-xxx-xxxx --set image.repository=docker.qa.xxx-xxxx.xxxx:8443/xxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxx-pr --set image.tag=pr-214-16 --set fullnameOverride=-xxx-xxx-xxx-pr-pr --wait xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx-pr-pr ./base-0.1.0.tgz --set imageSecretName=docker-registry --set service.type=ClusterIP --set resources.limits.cpu=0.5 --set resources.limits.memory=1024Mi --set resources.requests.cpu=0.5 --set resources.requests.memory=1024Mi --set labels.env=qa --set service.port=8080 --set service.port=8080 --set service.host=null.qa.xxx-xxxx.
```

Comment: Have you look at @Sanat Rohatgi answer ? Can you describe you pod and paste the output ?

Comment: Did link mentioned by @rohatgisanat helped https://github.com/helm/helm/issues/7426#issuecomment-579807064 ?  Please paste details from comment section to post  your post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to get the main error is by checking the pod while it is still running. Most of the time the issue is due to the application unable to start due to an underlying issues like liveness and readiness probe  failures, crashloopback errors etc. Then the pod get terminated and causes helm atomic timeout after the deployment time elapse

Answer (score 1):

Try to set higher value of timeout.
Also you can upgrade kubectl.
Take a look here: [helm-upgrade-timeout-atomic](https://gitmemory.com/issue/helm/helm/5377/472883853).

Problem is also described here: [helm-upgrade-timeout](https://github.com/helm/charts/issues/11904).

They claimed that is fixed in [#7653](https://github.com/helm/helm/pull/7653) which is included in `v3.2.1`.

However I read that  [#7653](https://github.com/helm/helm/pull/7653) may only allows previously failed releases to be upgraded **when there have been no successful releases**.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please add more details? Usually information like what was being done,how it was being done are great indicators for finding the problem.

Also look at this issue/question here to see if [this](https://github.com/helm/helm/issues/7426) solves your problem.

Comment: [2021-02-02T07:44:38.872Z] + helm upgrade --atomic --timeout 600s --install --namespace xxxx-xxx-xxxx --set image.repository=docker.qa.xxx-xxxx.xxxx:8443/xxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxx-pr --set image.tag=pr-214-16 --set fullnameOverride=-xxx-xxx-xxx-pr-pr --wait xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx-pr-pr ./base-0.1.0.tgz --set imageSecretName=docker-registry --set service.type=ClusterIP --set resources.limits.cpu=0.5 --set resources.limits.memory=1024Mi --set resources.requests.cpu=0.5 --set resources.requests.memory=1024Mi --set labels.env=qa --set service.port=8080 --set service.port=8080 --set service.host=null.qa.xxx-xxxx.

Comment: I think this link would help https://github.com/helm/helm/issues/7426#issuecomment-579807064

Comment: Thanks. The issue has been fixed.

Comment: What was the issue and how was it fixed?

Comment: @AfolabiOmotoso This is bad SO etiquette. If it is fixed state how it was fixed for the next person.